# Limitations on editing a SO post

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I've recently learned how to properly line break with two spaces at the end of a line.
So I tried editing a post that had lists and stuff without proper linebreaks.  Two spaces at the end of each line solved it... until the edit was rejected because it had less than 6 non-space characters.  So I put in a few `<br/>` tags, and it happily accepted those.

So, should my edit have been accepted?  Is the system's discrimination between them intentional or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of an edge condition, but I'll tell you the same thing I tell everyone:

*Is that post otherwise so perfect (apart from formatting) that NOTHING in it can be improved?*

Hint: the answer is no. :)

Comment: With respect to what you're saying, but trying to understand fully: I have run across several questions recently where the code has type arguments, e.g., Bind<T>().To<T>(). These type arguments are relevant to the question, but if the OP forgets to format properly, we can't see them readily. In other cases, the question is about an invisible chunk of HTML. Often, making code visible **really is** all that one might see to improve. In the case that spelling and grammar check out, are you saying we should alter the OP's prose for no real reason? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I am commenting here because I came into Meta today for the express purpose of asking about the Bind<T> situation and found this question already existed.