# Difference between tags on meta and tags on the main site

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, meta

I'm just bracing myself for this question to be brutally closed as a duplicate, but hear me out.

It's happened more that once that I've been reading a question or an answer and someone types `[tag:status-declined]`, rather than `[meta-tag:status-declined]`. (See the difference? [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)). It pains me so to see these tags misused, that I go in and edit them mercifully, but my edit of `meta-` is only 5 characters. Please, can we reduce the edit limit to 5 characters, even just for Meta?

[image]

Comment: Brace yourselves. Close votes are coming.

Comment: But yeah, hilarity aside, I agree with this proposal. Upvoting... now!

Comment: +1 This is the most eminently reasonable request for a policy change I have ever seen. Voting to close (just kidding.)

Comment: Would have been better with a screenshot and some hand-drawn red circles though.

Comment: If we give him enough up-votes, he'll be able to edit these tags himself! +1

Comment: My opinion, seriously, is changing [tag...] to [meta-tag...] without changing anything else is _too minor._ Seriously. And that has got nothing to do with the fact that you edited m- oh, never mind.

Answer (score 3):

This is just another side-effect of the editing restrictions, which don't exist once you have full editing privileges at 2,000 reputation. There have been many different proposals with many different reasons for reducing or eliminating the minimum character change, all rejected. Why should this be any different?

Someone will fix it eventually if there's *really* nothing else in the post that you need to change. However, I don't see any need to go changing the minimum for such a minor and rare case.

In your specific case, people typing [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) will likely not cause many people to actually *click* on that tag. Most people here know what the status-declined tag is, and the only really convenience over using `meta-tag` instead of just `tag` is that you get the red box with it.

Comment: but...but...pretty red box...

Comment: I disagree that visuals would be the only difference.  [Sometimes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140292/182803) the link points to a different tag, and can be positively misleading.  However, I [agree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140292/182803) with you regarding the conclusion.