# Why is there a 6 character requirement when reviewing questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should edits be at least six non-space characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140288/why-should-edits-be-at-least-six-non-space-characters)

I was reviewing a question on stackoverflow today.  According to the yellow box on the right side of the window I am encouraged to correct minor grammatical or spelling errors.  So I attempted to do this and was unable to save it.  In this case the OP mispelled maybe.  Why is this restriction in place?  Seems kinda silly to me.