# I can't fix a typo in an answer to my question

Tags: support, suggested-edits

There is an [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1089402) to my question in which the user typed **recovation**. I can't change it to **revocation** because of limits of Stack Exchange. Why do we need those limits???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should edits be at least six non-space characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140288/why-should-edits-be-at-least-six-non-space-characters)

Comment: See our FAQ on suggested edits, [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), section *Is there a minimum change threshold for a suggested edit?*

Comment: For another time, [ping me](https://twitter.com/PeterMortensen) on Twitter (e.g., with hashtag `#EditRequest` and a Server Fault link), and I will do the edit. Expect a delay of up to 48 hours. (You could have got past the character limit *alone* by dressing the naked link. *TXT record* (DNS) was also misspelled. An alternative is to post a comment first to try to get the user to do it (though the success rate is often low).)

Answer (score 4):

We have restrictions so that spam isn't edited into posts mainly, but also so that people who don't know how sites work don't change things in unexpected ways simply because they are unaware of the rules and conventions.

We also want edits to be substantial and to correct everything that's wrong in a post. We don't want to have to do it in multiple passes.

Once you've [enough rep to be trusted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) you can edit anything.

regarding that particular answer

- it could stand to have info corrected to information
- you could edit the link so that the words "this information" become the link itself rather than having the URL visible since the URL isn't something you really need to read inline. That will still allow the link to show on hover.

Those suggestions, together with the word you want to change will put you over the 6 character limit and allow you to submit your suggested edit.